# Functions only works once and in descending order

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of a div by pressing another div, but it only works once and in descending order. I have just about zero experience with JavaScript so i might be doing it totally wrong.

```
document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.farge').classList.add('transition-red');
    });

    document.getElementById('orange').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.farge').classList.add('transition-orange');
    });

    document.getElementById('yellow').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.farge').classList.add('transition-yellow');
    });

    document.getElementById('green').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.farge').classList.add('transition-green');
    });

    document.getElementById('turquoise').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.farge').classList.add('transition-turquoise');
    });

    document.getElementById('blue').addEventListener('click', function  () {
    document.querySelector('.farge').classList.add('transition-blue');
    });

    document.getElementById('purple').addEventListener('click', function  () {
    document.querySelector('.farge').classList.add('transition-purple');
    });

    document.getElementById('pink').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.farge').classList.add('transition-pink');
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="farge-valg-panel">
            <table id="farge-table">
                <tr id="farge-tr">
                    <td id="red"></td>
                    <td id="orange"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="farge-tr">
                    <td id="yellow"></td>
                    <td id="green"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="farge-tr">
                    <td id="turquoise"></td>
                    <td id="blue"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="farge-tr">
                    <td id="purple"></td>
                    <td id="pink"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="farge"></div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    farge{
    transition-duration: 2s;
    grid-area: main;
    background-color: black;
}

.transition-red{
    background-color: red;
}

.transition-orange{
    background-color: orange;
}

.transition-yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.transition-green{
    background-color: green;
}

.transition-turquoise{
    background-color: turquoise;
}

.transition-blue{
    background-color: blue;
}

.transition-purple{
    background-color: purple;
}

.transition-pink{
    background-color: pink;
}
```

The JavaScript ads css to the "farge" element (i have to do it this way because it's for a school project that requires animation).

Comment: can you make simple reproducible example of your code includeing css and html as well?

Comment: can you add your HTML code as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove other classes, or it will only work in descending order which is following your CSS.

```js
function toggleColor(color) {
  const element = document.querySelector('.farge');
  // Diable All Color
  element.classList.remove('transition-red');
  element.classList.remove('transition-orange');
  element.classList.remove('transition-yellow');
  element.classList.remove('transition-green');
  element.classList.remove('transition-turquoise');
  element.classList.remove('transition-blue');
  element.classList.remove('transition-purple');
  element.classList.remove('transition-pink');

  // Enable Specific Color
  element.classList.add(color);
}

document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', function () {
  toggleColor('transition-red');
});

document.getElementById('orange').addEventListener('click', function () {
  toggleColor('transition-orange');
});

document.getElementById('yellow').addEventListener('click', function () {
  toggleColor('transition-yellow');
});

document.getElementById('green').addEventListener('click', function () {
  toggleColor('transition-green');
});

document.getElementById('turquoise').addEventListener('click', function () {
  toggleColor('transition-turquoise');
});

document.getElementById('blue').addEventListener('click', function  () {
  toggleColor('transition-blue');
});

document.getElementById('purple').addEventListener('click', function  () {
  toggleColor('transition-purple');
});

document.getElementById('pink').addEventListener('click', function () {
  toggleColor('transition-pink');
}
```